# Perfmon remote connection failing between two w7 pc's

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, perfmon

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate and trying to connect to the perfmon service of another (local network) w7 box. We have windows firewall turned off, the appropriate users added to the Performance Log Users, Administrators and (just in case) Performance Monitor Users.

We have the Performance Count DLL Host and Performance Logs & Alerts servics running under Local Service.

We still get a "cannot connect to machine" error when entering the remote computer name for the stat (browsing finds the machine, but will not connect).

Anything we are missing or is this a new "security feature" waiting to be service packed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Starting the Remote Registry Service.

Comment: Added the RPC services too and that may have done the trick.

Comment: I'd assumed it would be running - RPC would definitely be required.